# Do remote debugger and mobile emulation work together in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, remote-debugging, mobileemulation

I was trying to capture browser's image in a certain resolution from the existing browser, so I tried to use both remote debugger and mobile emulation. They worked well respectively, which I could capture image of that resolution, or connect to remote debugger. While putting these two together,

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: mobileEmulation
```

mobile emulation seems not to be working properly.

This is the code I am using, I was trying to get these two to function simultaneously, or other ways to capture image of fixed resolution in an existing browser window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

mobile_emulation = {"deviceMetrics": {"width": 1920, "height": 1080, "pixelRatio": 1.0}}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
chrome_options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222"
s = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.bing.com/")
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```